# Any variant to run android emulator without kvm support?

Tags: android, freebsd

Since last update, android emulator refuses to run on a machine without KVM support. 
Is there any way to get older emulator version to run Emulator w/o he emulation? 
Which was this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com)  ?